# Not administrator - manage users

Tags: users

I have a user "manager". This user has the manager role but not the administrative role. Is it possible to allow this user to manage users and their roles? For example, if someone creates an account I want this user to be able to activate the account like an administrator can? And then to give a role to that user?

Or even change roles of existing user?

I have searched. But no luck.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't understand why Kevin's answer hasn't been accepted yet, here you go with a snip of the permissions that need to be enabled.
[image]

Have a look at this module- [Administer Users by Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole)
These are the new permissions that come with the module -

NEW PERMISSIONS
1 )Access the users overview page
  See the list of users at admin/people.  Only users that can be edited are shown.

2) Create new users
  Create users, at admin/people/create.

3) Edit users with no custom roles
  Allows editing of any authenticated user that has no custom roles set.

4) Edit users with role XXX
  Allows editing of any authenticated user with the specified role.
  To edit a user with multiple roles, the sub-admin must have permission to
  edit ALL of those roles.  ("Edit users with no custom roles" is NOT needed.)

-The permission for cancel work exactly the same as those for edit.

Comment: Thanks but does that mean this user will be able to manage the administrator aswell since he will have all the permissions?

Comment: Absolutely. This user can add/delete admins as well.

Comment: Yah so this is not what Im looking for.. I just want him to be able to manage all users appart from admin user

Comment: Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Role Delegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module. Some details from its project page:

> ... allows site administrators to grant specific roles the authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the administer permissions permission.
>
> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role permission to allow the assignment of that role.
>
> The module also adds an assign all roles permission. Enabling this permission for a role is a convenient way to allow the assignment of any other role without having to check all the assign ROLE role permissions on the permissions page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This role needs the "administer users" and "administer roles and permissions" permission to do this; plus all applicable permission to access the backend to get to the users overview page.